# Cannot flush proxy settings after being connected to Squid proxy

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy, squid

My computer was recently on a LAN with a squid proxy. After returning to my home network, certain applications (that I'm assuming were proxied) are still attempting to connect to the local proxy (10.1.1.7:3128), seen here:
[Connections outbound to stale proxy IP and port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pULyI.png)

These are the steps I've done to clear out any stale settings:

1. Internet Options>Connections>LAN settings> uncheck "Automatically detect settings"
2. ipconfig /release
3. ipconfig /renew
4. ipconfig /flushdns
5. ipconfig /registerdns
6. arp -d *
7. nbtstat -R
8. netsh winsock reset
9. del \wpad*.dat /s
10. created regkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\EnableAutoproxyResultCache:0

Additionally, when I run the network troubleshooter it shows that the "device or resource (www.microsoft.com) is not responding" [Network Diagnostics Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVifL.png)

I have no issues browsing to any website

I have no ideas on what to try next so feedback would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Possible dupe: [How Windows automatically detects proxy settings](//superuser.com/q/1361923)

Comment: In an admin cmd prompt, what does the output of running:
`netsh winhttp show proxy` show?  You should run it from \windows\syswow64\ as well if it's 64-bit OS to see the setting for 32-bit processes.  Does it say "Direct access (no proxy server)." for both?

Comment: Wpad is not a file. Does the solution in the link given by DavidPostill help?

Comment: @HelpingHand Here is the output:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Proxy Server(s) :  10.1.1.7:3128
    Bypass List     :  (none)

Comment: In that case, run: "netsh winhttp reset proxy".

Comment: Awesome, that seems to have worked!

Comment: Was it just the 64-bit processes? Running the command from syswow64 didn't have it listed?

Comment: I ran the command from the default command prompt location of C:\WINDOWS\system32. Running it after the reset in SysWOW64 shows no proxy server

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:

1. Run Command Prompt as administrator
2. Verify current winhttp proxy settings: "**netsh winhttp show proxy**"
3. If it shows "Proxy Server(s): *IP Address:Port*" do step 4
4. Run "**netsh winhttp reset proxy**"

Since I am a new contributor I cannot mark a comment as the answer so thanks to @HelpingHand.